# Problem using symfony 4.3.5 the Form folder doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to follow this tutorial in order to discover symfony 4.3.5 .
[https://www.adcisolutions.com/knowledge/getting-started-rest-api-symfony-4][1]

In this tutorial like in many others, they suppose that there is a Form folder that is automatically generatd by symfony/skeleton.

Unfortunately for me, I don't have this folder after trying ten times installing symfony 4.3.5 in different projects. In the src folder, all the things required for me are present except the Form folder.
I tried to resolve the problem by installing symfony/form. But, the Form folder isn't created.

Do the symfony developers removed it or replaced it with something elsewhere? Can ytou help me plz? I'm stuck since yesterday and I didn't found a solution yet.

Thx in advance

Comment: just add a Form folder in the src directory manually

Comment: Some recipes, e.g. orm, will create folders for you. When installing forms this does not happen, but feel free to create it. The reason why the orm recipe creates the `src/Entity/`-folder for you is that there is some doctrine-related configuration that needs to know that entity-classes are stored there. Since your forms are configured automatically based on their type, i.e. because they extend `AbstractType`, no matter their name no directory is created for you. The directory structure under `src/` is entirely up to you. Feel free to create a directory `src/Form` for your FormType-classes.

Comment: thx for the explanation that really helped me to understand this framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed the skeleton, so it comes with the basic components to run. 
Install maker bundle:

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

And  `php bin/console make:form FormNameType`

It will create the Form directory on your project.

Hope it helps

Comment: thx for the help it worked thx to your recommandations and those above :)

Comment: Glad to help! :)